# ffserver supplying wrong MIME type for mp4

Tags: internet-explorer, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mime-types, ffserver

I have a video stream I am streaming from ffserver that works fine on the webm side (in Chrome), however the h264/mp4 side does not work, at least not in Internet Explorer.

Internet Explorer supplies an error of: 'MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type'

Looking at what is going on in fiddler it appears that it is using a header containing:

**Content-Type: application/mp4**

Shouldn't that type be **video/mp4** ?

In ffserver this particular stream is configured as:

```
<Stream 720.mp4>
Feed 720_h264.ffm
Format mp4
NoAudio
VideoCodec libx264
VideoSize 1280x720
VideoFrameRate 5
VideoBitRate 4096
VideoBufferSize 40000
AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
AVOptionVideo qmin 10
AVOptionVideo qmax 42
VideoGopSize 32
PreRoll 5
StartSendOnKey
</Stream>
```

Does anyone know how to force or correct the header set by ffserver to (presumably) make MSIE happy?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, this is hardcoded in movenc.c, and there's no way to change it, so you'd have to change the source code and recompile. I'd also recommend to send a patch to the project to fix it upstream.

```
../libavformat/movenc.c:    .mime_type         = "application/mp4",
../libavformat/movenc.c:    .mime_type         = "application/mp4",
../libavformat/movenc.c:    .mime_type         = "application/mp4",
```

Comment: Fixed upstream in this commit: http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=0054d5ac02eaf37d7cfa63efa6e278b5f749c0c6

Comment: Thanks, it looks like its fixed in the newest version included in Ubuntu sources now.

Comment: Yeah, that's http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=0054d5ac02eaf37d7cfa63efa6e278b5f749c0c6 ("BBB on irc" is me).